# Write a sequence of h264 frames into several files

Tags: c++, h.264, specifications, live555

I have a stream of h264 frames (from RTSP stream, but i think it is irrelevant), I know *sequence parameter set* bytes and I want to write these frames to disk in several .h264 files (around N frames each).

If I write

```
sequence parameter set - 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 - frame1 - 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 - frame2 - 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 - frame3 -
```

and so on to a disk (without dashes, just a bunch of bytes) , i will get a correct file (at least, it can be played via vlc)

But if i will write files:

```
sequence parameter set - 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 - frame1 - ...
sequence parameter set - 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 - frameN - ...
sequence parameter set - 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 - frame2N - ...
sequence parameter set - 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 - frame3N - ...
```

when some of them will be correct (in the sence of been playable by vlc), and some of them not (and not only the first file is correct!) 
Apparently, not every frame can be at start of an h264 file, but which can? Or which is correct way of storing h264 frames in different files?

Speaking of tools, i'm using c++ with [live555](http://www.live555.com) library, and can get frame types using [h264bitstream](https://github.com/aizvorski/h264bitstream) library, but I guess it does not matter.
I do not want to use any command line tools (like ffmpeg), but a solution which could be implemented in c++ with some additional libraries.

Comment: There are three types of frames in h.264. I, P and B frames. P and B frames are coded as differences from a previous frame. Thus, by themselves they cannot be displayed. Only I frames are "self contained". My guess is that the ones that work, happens to start with an I frame.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be playable (without other information), each file should contains :

- SPS (Sequence Parameter Set)
- PPS (Picture Parameter Set)
- I Frame (could be and IDR or a SLICE_I)

Next the decoder can decode other slices type (P, B).

A simple way to do this is to store the incoming SPS & PPS frames and write them (with the 00 00 00 01 start code) before each IDR frame (also with the 00 00 00 01 start code).